# Some azure cli commands return SubscriptionNotExists errors?

Tags: azure, azure-cli

I have a free trial subscription on Azure:

```sh
$ az account subscription list                  
                                                                                         
Command group 'account subscription' is experimental and under development. Reference and support levels: https://aka.ms/CLI_refstatus
[
  {
    "authorizationSource": "RoleBased",
    "displayName": "Azure subscription 1",
    "id": "/subscriptions/fffffff-ffff-ffff-ffff-ffffffffffff",
    "state": "Enabled",
    "subscriptionId": "fffffff-ffff-ffff-ffff-ffffffffffff",
    "subscriptionPolicies": {
      "locationPlacementId": "Public_2014-09-01",
      "quotaId": "FreeTrial_2014-09-01",
      "spendingLimit": "On"
    }
  }
]
```

but when I execute the command (list MariaDB SKUs) I get the following error:

```sh
$ az mariadb server list-skus --location eastus       
                                                                                  
(SubscriptionNotExists) Subscription 'fffffff-ffff-ffff-ffff-ffffffffffff' does not exist.
Code: SubscriptionNotExists
Message: Subscription 'fffffff-ffff-ffff-ffff-ffffffffffff' does not exist.
```

Works fine under my other account where I have a pay-as-you-go subscription. Same thing with the go SDK.

If the free trial is the issue it would be great to document it somewhere.

Comment: Are you able to login to Az correctly using:

Connect-AzAccount -Tenant xxxxx -Subscription xxxxx

Comment: @PratikSomaiya I'm not using powershell, I use az cli

Comment: Could you please try to login using `az login` and run the script again

Comment: @AjayKumarGhose-MT I did try login multiple time with multiple accounts

Comment: May i know From your free trail subscription only ! are you able to login ..? Or you can use `az account set --subscription 00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000` then run the above command for list the maria db server skus

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Turns out you have to register [provider resources](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/management/resource-providers-and-types) for your subscription before you can use them. For some reason MariaDB was already registered for one of my accounts but not for the other. The error `SubscriptionNotExists` is extremely confusing in that regard.

Answer (score 0):

To list the skus list Mariadb Please make sure that you have logged in successfully using `az login` cmdlet .

Then try to execute the following command which you are using

```
az mariadb server list-skus --location eastus
```

***OUTPUT FOR REFERENCE:-***
[image]
[image]

***NOTE:- Try to close and reopen your terminal and use az login and choose your account in which you have free trail subscription then use the command.***

*As i don't have any free trial subscription to test it on my environment .*

***AFAIK, we can use it For free trail account as well based on the below screenshot and also can Check this*** [***Microsoft Document***](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/mariadb/concepts-pricing-tiers) :
[image]

For more details please refer the below links for Azure free trial supported resources:

- ***MICROSOFT DOCUMENTATION:-*** [***Azure free account FAQ***](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/free/free-account-faq/) ,[***Azure subscription and service limits, quotas, and constraints***](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/management/azure-subscription-service-limits) & [***az mariadb server list-skus***](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/mariadb/server?view=azure-cli-latest#az-mariadb-server-list-skus)